# how to save CCMenuItemToggle sound state

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I would like to save the sound state when I use the toggle so that when I restart the game it is unchanged. How can I do this? Please see the relevant code below.

```
-(void)volumeItems {

// volume toggle
CCMenuItemImage *vON = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"volumeON.png" selectedImage:@"volumeOFF.png"];
CCMenuItemImage *vOFF = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"volumeOFF.png" selectedImage:@"volumeON.png"];
vToggle = [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self selector:@selector(volumeSel:) items:vON , vOFF , nil];
      .
      .
      .
}

-(void)volumeSel:(id)sender  {

switch (vToggle.selectedIndex) {
    case 0:
        if (![[SettingsManager sharedSettingsManager] isVolON]) {
            [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"song.mp3"];
            [[[SettingsManager sharedSettingsManager] setIsVolON:YES];
        }
        CCLOG(@"ON");
        break;
    case 1:
        if ([[[SettingsManager sharedSettingsManager] isVolON]) {
            [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
            [[[SettingsManager sharedSettingsManager] setIsVolON:NO];
        }
        CCLOG(@"oFF");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just save your volume values to user defaults whenever you turn them on/off.

```
BOOL musicOn = [[[SettingsManager sharedSettingsManager] isVolON];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:musicOn forKey:@"music"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To read from user defaults on next launch

```
BOOL isMusicOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"music"];
```